# How to do a .Find on an inheritance entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two entities in this case : `Membre` inherits from `Utilisateur`.

I have a ListView so I want to show the `Membre` that is currently showed. The line that is generating the error is

```
Membre lemembre = (lecontexte.Set<Membre>().Find(membrealecran.Pseudo));
```

All I want this line to do is do a `.Find(membrealecran.Pseudo)`... But I can't use the `.Find` on `Set<Membre>`.

It generates an System.ArgumentException and Data.EntitySqlException. It says Int32 and String are incompatible for the operation...

I can do a `.Find` on `Utilisateur`, but not on `Membre`. Why? How could I do a `Find` on `Membre`?

```
protected void lvInscription_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    using (modele_vivo_amoreContainer lecontexte = new modele_vivo_amoreContainer())
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {
                Membre membrealecran = (Membre)e.Item.DataItem;
                Membre lemembre = (lecontexte.Set<Membre>().Find(membrealecran.Pseudo));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text += "ERREUR DE ITEMDATABOUND, " + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Naming your context 'lecontexte' is like naming a string 'thestring'

Comment: @YoryeNathan I think this is how french works "le big mac"

Comment: @YoryeNathan better than something with *amoreContainer* (the class' name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Find` are seaching for entity by primary key. You need to pass primary key as parameter. Use `SingleOrDefault` for seaching by non primary key param:

```
...
Membre lemembre = lecontexte.Set<Membre>().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Pseudo == membrealecran.Pseudo);
```